# What is the regex for a Monero address or Payment ID?

Tags: payment-id, address

What is the best, most correct way of regex'ing the address and payment ID for Monero?

Comment: To avoid duplication can you edit this question to better emphasize how it is different? Perhaps focus on the payment ID part (or an integrated address) which was not discussed in the previous question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Monero address:

```
4[0-9AB][123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz]{93}
```

A payment ID:

```
([0-9a-fA-F]{16}|[0-9a-fA-F]{64})
```

Comment: [0-9a-fA-F]{64}

Comment: I believe `|` is useless in the first regexp

Comment: The `|` was actually an error (worse than useless) because it would match a literal pipe character.  Now fixed.

Comment: Address could be reduced: `^4[0-9AB][1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{93}$`

Comment: Can you update to include subaddresses please?